# how to not submit a form in js

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to not submit the form if the inputs are empty, here is my code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>
The X/O Game
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var check = function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    var o = document.getElementById("o").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("p").value;

    if(p==""||(x==""&&o=="")){
        alert("fill the form!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};

$('#formm').submit(function(e){
    var shouldSubmit = check();

    if (!shouldSubmit) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }                                    
});

$('#emotion input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#emotion label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
<body>
<div>
Please enter your name & choose your character before start playing:
</div>
<div>
<form method=post action=game.php name="formm">
Name:<br>
<input type=text name=player id=p>
</div>
<div>
Character:<br>
<input 
  type="radio" name="emotion" value="xChar"
  id="x" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="x">
  <img src="images/x.png " />
</label>
<input 
  type="radio" name="emotion" value="oChar"
  id="o" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="o">
  <img src="images/o.png" />
</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type=submit value=Play>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

    $('#formm').submit(function(){
        return  f;                                       
    });
```

this function is called when the user clicks on the submit button.
the form is subbmited even though the inputs are empty, where is the wrong?

Comment: Try to not change the question, then you will falsify answers

Answer (score 1):

`f` is defined when you call `check()`, they will not magically update. Do the checks inside the submit function.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use HTML5 `required` attribute here:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="x" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you want more complex validation, you should have a look at [html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/?redirect_from_locale=cs). The form validation should move from Javascript to HTML now (or in the near future).

But if you want to do it your way, do as epascarello suggests here:

```
$('#formm').submit(function(){
    check();
    return  f;                                       
});
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, though his logic appears to be a little more verbose than just required (`p==""||(x==""&&o=="")`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#yoursubmitbtnid').click(function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    var o = document.getElementById("o").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("p").value;

    if(p==""||(x=="" && o=="")){
        alert("fill the form!");
        return false;
    }                                     
});
```

Comment: be careful not to return false when you mean to just stop the event default behavior. this will break bubbling and event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the check function in the submit handler to determine whether or not the submit should be allowed.

```
var check = function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    var o = document.getElementById("o").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("p").value;

    if(p==""||(x==""&&o=="")){
        alert("fill the form!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};

$('#formm').submit(function(e){
    var shouldSubmit = check();

    if (!shouldSubmit) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }                                    
});
```

You may want to look into using a validation plugin (such as [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)) if you plan on doing any extensive client side validation.

Comment: it seems as the most suitable answer, but its not working either :( ,  i'll post the all code of my page.

Comment: @user2996426 you're binding event handlers to elements before they exist. HTML in parsed only once from top to bottom. Put your jquery code inside of a `$(document).ready()` or move it to the bottom of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the check function when the form is being submitted

```
$('#formm').submit(function(){
    return check();                                       
});
```

If the check function returns false then the form should not submit.